# Basic Auth with Traefik and Docker using Django cookiecutter

Tags: docker, basic-authentication, traefik

I use Docker with Traefik and Django cookiecutter. I want to add Basic Auth to it to shield it off. My docker compose yaml file looks like this:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  production_postgres_data: {}
  production_postgres_data_backups: {}
  production_traefik: {}

services:
  ...

  traefik:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/traefik/Dockerfile
    image: myod_production_traefik
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - production_traefik:/etc/traefik/acme:z
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:443"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=myod:$$2y$$05$......"

  ...
```

However when I run `docker-compose -f production.yml up` , I can still access the website without getting asked for authentication. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable HTTP Basic auth, using the middleware.
So you should add to labels:

```
traefik.http.returs.your-name-for-https-route.middlewares=auth
```

At least according this https://blog.creekorful.com/2020/01/how-to-expose-traefik-2-dashboard-securely-docker-swarm/ you should be able do it as you imagine.